# .htaccess url rewrite for single page website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a single page website that changes content based on variables passed through the URL with PHP.

For instance, my url displays as

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?section=home
www.mysite.com/index.php?section=about-us
```

so forth and so on, depending upon which link you click in the main navigation.

I want the urls to read as `www.mysite.com/home` or `www.mysite.com/about-us`.

My mod-rewrite feature is enabled because before I made this a one page site, it was functioning correctly.

I've tried this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've tried every suggestion I found on Google and on StackOverflow, nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Google 'Clean URL', 'pretty urls', 'url rewriting' etc. There are lots and lots of answers out there already.

Comment: The answers out there are pertinent to multipage websites it seems, not for websites that are single page. I will take your suggestion though and try looking again.

Comment: I'm actually using `RewriteRule`s for exactly the same purpose as you, a single page website. I'll post an example as an answer, because I promise it works.

Comment: That would be great because for some reason, I can't get any of the options I have found to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an `.htaccess` for exactly the same purpose, and it's working beautifully. My code is below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Naturally, if `index.php` isn't your main PHP file, replace that with what is. Also, replace `?id` with `?section` if your example code is what your using.

What the `[^/\.]+` means is saying `I need you to find text that contains anything but a period (.) or a forward slash (/), and there has to be at least one character in it.`

For an example, go to the website I'm using it on, [Northside Aikido](http://www.northsideaikido.com/).

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

**EDIT**

Note, this code won't turn `http://www.example.com/index.php?section=home` into `http://www.example.com/home` automagically, it'll just mean that the latter link works like the former. If you want it to automatically replace it, you'll need more code than one line.

Comment: I took what you have here and placed it in my htaccess file, yet I still get unclean urls.

Comment: Try going to `[page]/home` instead of `[page]/index.php?section=home`, as well.

Comment: Anytime :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Almost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your answer helped as well! Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

this is what im using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```